# EF: Searching for the newly created object in Database and update the old one in conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

We have a model named `Model1` and it has two attributes. `Model1.Time`, `Model1.Text` and `Model1.Value`, of course it has also ID as the requirement.

We are receiving the values from a SOAP service and registering them to our database but the question is: We have to check if these values are available already or not. What is the best possible way to do it?

Basically we are using a linq query.

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
var x = (from y in db.Models where y.Value != new.Value && y.Text != new.Text select y).toList();
if  { (x.Count == null) db.Models.Add(new); }
else {
foreach (var y in x) {
if (y.Time < new.Time) {
     y.Time = new.Time;
     y.Value = new.Value;
     y.Text = new.Text;
     db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(y, EntityState.Modified);
}
}
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Do you think that; this is the only possible approach or is there any more proper solution?

Comment: do you not get the id of your model back from request?

Comment: no there is no ID available. So EF is creating an increment ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the ID available from the service then I think what you have is the best you can do.  or at least the approximate best.  Hard to give you a better solution without knowing more about your use case or what you are trying to save.

Does what you have work?  Is there something more specific about the code you posted you need help with?